# Can not find Edit help

Tags: support, editing

I looked in the help center but could find no listing for help in editing.
Can someone point me the way?

Comment: What sort of help are you after? Could you be a bit more specific? Editing your posts? Other people's? Guidelines on when to edit? Help on the markdown format used on the site?

Comment: Which of https://askubuntu.com/help/editing, https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting and https://askubuntu.com/editing-help are you looking for?

Answer (score 7):

There's three help documents currently:

1. [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing)
2. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)
3. [Markdown Editing Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

For comments, you need to refer to the Meta.SE post called [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and read through that on how comments work, including formatting.

If none of these are the specific "editing help" page you are looking for, then you need to specify what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I ended lines with 2 spaces but it created no newlines. To be honest, compared with other forums, the editing abilities are obtuse.

Comment: FYI This is not a forum site ;)  I would need to see the specific thing you're looking at, but if you mean a line break *between* content just use two hits of the "enter" or "return" key.

Comment: @fixit7 if you could explain what you're typing in, and what you're expecting, we might be able to help moreso.

Comment: I am trying to edit my last comment located here so it looks right. I tried indenting my code in geany 4 spaces and pasting it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057717/script-help-closing-a-program-after-set-amount-of-time?noredirect=1#comment1729981_1057717

Comment: @fixit7 The double-space line break item in the editing guide **does not work** within a code block, as the code block applies "preformatted text" format to the code, and not the standard Markdown to it.  Paste your code into your question as it looks in your script, and then select all of it, and apply code formatting with the button that looks like "{ }", it should then apply code formatting properly.

Comment: I did so. I saw no {} button? I am trying to edit comment. I do see the symbol if posting a new question. @Thomas Ward

Comment: You are not understanding my last post. I want to edit my COMMENT. Not my post. I added code to my post. Looks good. :-)

Comment: @fixit7 you can only edit your comment for 5 minutes, and *comments* do not support multiline posts nor do they support most of the markdown formatting except for backticks for single-line preformatted text bits, bold, italic, etc.  I added the Meta.SE post about comments to my post as a link.